# MS MPI does not execute MPI program

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mpi, ms-mpi

I have used MS MPI to develop an MPI program. The program is tested and it works fine.

When I try to run the program in `cmd` using the following command:

```
mpiexec -n 4 a.exe
```

the console hangs and it does not execute the program. If I try to interrupt using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the message `mpiexec aborting job...` appears and nothing exits until I manually kill `smpd.exe`.
I use `MS Windows 7 64bit`. The same problem appears when using another machine with this OS. However, everything works fine on a `MS Windows 10` machine.
I'd appreciate any clue to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is using the latest version of MS MPI runtime which is v9 at the time of writing. I installed the previous version (i.e. v8) and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be when `mpiexec` calls to `smpd.exe` to run the application.  The `smpd.exe` process starts and gets stuck in a suspended state.  You can go into the windows resource monitor and resume the service, and your program will start normally.

[image]